# Storage URL or IP of server on android

Tags: android, security, url, storage

I'd like to know how to store the url or IP address and secured strips ( information to access to the server) on android application

Comment: I dont fully understand the question. What are these strips? Passwords or something similar? 

This question needs rewording.

Comment: Strip = IP
My need is to make the IP of server invisible in the code

Comment: If you don't want anyone with the APK to have access to that data, then don't ship it in the APK. Distribute it separately to the users you trust, and have them enter it into the application. Your application can store it using `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: the  application is  designed to everyone but i must secured access to the sever

Answer (score 1):

Trying to hide information "in plain sight" is bound to fail. You could devise a really complicated algorithm to not have to store the actual IP, but it would be really easy to just see what network activity there is and find the IP out that way!

Security by obscurity is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) tecniques in order to store and retrieve variables related to the application, but if values to store are constans they just could be declared in a final class like this:

```
public final class ServerValues {
         public static final String SERVER_IP = "http://your.server.link/";
         public static final String SERVER_ROOT= "/";
         public static final String USERNAME= "username";
         public static final String PASSWORD= "password";
...
}
```

In this case you simply access to constants of this class to retieve server values.

Comment: thank you already for your answer 
May be poorly explained my need 
I want a method that allows me to hide my SERVER_IP 
because if someone decompile my code it will find it easily

Comment: @MrZ you can always edit your question and make it more understandable

Comment: I want a technique that allows me to secure and hide the IP address of my server.
because if someone decompile the APK, he will easily find the information of my server